# Splitting into two Rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table which will have two columns ID and NAME in which NAME format is A-123-B-456.
This combination of A with a number and B with a number will be unique.

```
1  A-123-B-456
```

I want two rows of this one data like

```
1  A-123-B-456
2  B-456-A-123.
```

Please help to convert into this format.

Comment: Convert as in...? Update the contents of the table? If so, what happens to a potentially pre-existing row with id 2 in the above example? Also, are the numbers always 3 digits?

Comment: need to construct a View which will convert do this..numbers can be 4 digit as well but a delimiter will always be there.

Comment: ...and existing id 1 will be 1&2, what will existing id 2 be? 3&4?

Comment: Also, if it is required to keep the digits constant then that can be done as i will add a '0' if a three digit number and make it to always 4. Please help in this..not getting idea how to use CONNECT_BY here..

Comment: no modification in the ID. View will just display the name as in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, this is the view you need, it will keep the same id on both rows;

```
CREATE VIEW Table1View AS
  SELECT id, name FROM Table1
  UNION
  SELECT id, 
    SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name, '-', 1, 2) +1) || '-' || 
    SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name, '-', 1, 2) -1) name FROM Table1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8136e/1).

EDIT: To have a join and just manipulate `name` and keep the rest, you can use a CTE to do your original query and do a UNION on that instead;

```
CREATE VIEW Table1View AS
  WITH cte AS (                -- your original join goes here
    SELECT Table1.id, Table1.name, Table2.extra 
    FROM Table1
    JOIN Table2
      ON Table1.id = Table2.id
  )
  SELECT id, name, extra FROM cte
  UNION
  SELECT id, 
    SUBSTR(name, INSTR(name, '-', 1, 2) +1) || '-' || 
    SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name, '-', 1, 2) -1) name, extra 
  FROM cte;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da8de/1).

Comment: Thanks Joachim..but this will not work for me as my view query is like select T1.name,T2.style from Table1 T1 join Table2 T2 on T1.col1=T2.col2 where T1.col1 like 'T%'; Please let me know if this can be twisted..

Comment: @RaghavTandon Could you add a real example of data/desired result to your question then? Your question says nothing about two tables, a view or other fields.

Comment: You understood it right but if u c my view query then i have to fetch record from  multiple tables and multiple joins are involved. The base table for this is Table1 in which i will get the records starting with T and for each record I should get two rows like T-123-B-456 then the view should display T-123-B-456 and B-456-T-123 along with the other columns as well..

Comment: So in this case i will not be able to use a UNION operator for Name column only..Please tell me how to convert this one row data to two rows rest joins and all i will take care.

Comment: @RaghavTandon Updated with an example combining it with a join.

Comment: @Joachim..thanks a lot for this...this will work..what is CTE in oracle....it is looking like a temporary table kind of thing to me..Please explain and also what is the performance hit as the view has to fetch a lot of data and the query of view is also very complex...

Comment: Also is this applicabel in 10g?

Comment: A `CTE` is called a `Common Table Expression`, and it exists in many SQL databases (MySQL excepted). I suggest you google it, since the topic is big. As for performance, if the view is heavily queried, you always have the option to create it as a [materialized view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm), that makes the view into what could be seen as a table on which you can put indexes. If you're searching on `name` in the view, it's definitely going to improve read performance drastically. And yes, afaik, both CTEs and materialized views work well in 10g.

Comment: @Joachim..yeahi am using materialized view only on top of view...thanks..i will see the performance hit..